# Community Builder's Register button not showing

Tags: extensions

Implemented [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder) extension on client's website [tnssecurities.in](http://www.tnssecurities.in/). While Login form showing, Register button not showing. Tried to post this problem on their forum but came to know forum membership not free.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your module doesn't have registration button coding **or** check your
backend -> Extension manager -> Module manager -> Select your module and check if any options are available for show registration button in your site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Community Builder Login module.
In this module there are several tabs. In the tab Login Options, you need the setting Register Login Link. When it is set to Hide you will not see a link to register: set it to one of the other 3 values (Text, Icon, or Icon and text).

The forum is free, you need to register first, and some parts of the forum are read only when you do not have a paid subscription.

Success.

Paul

Comment: Register button not showing despite enabling Text, Icon, or Icon and Text.

Comment: The login module on your site is not the cb module, but a k2 module??

Comment: The k2 module is subsequently installed because of failure implementing cb module. Ironically, k2 does not show Register button!

Comment: Once again trying to move forward with CB Login which is not showing Register button despite enabling Register option (www.tnssecurities.in, CB Login button placed on top right side bar.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me either until I realised that on the Configuration page of Community Builder, the first option entitled "Allow User Registration" should be set on "Yes, Independent of CMS 'Allow Registration'".  This, unless you are wanting the Content Management System (in my case Joomla) to do all the registration.

Comment: Thank you for contributing Bill.  Please take the [tour].